# CSS - Can I use an object's Width in Calc()?

Tags: css, calc

I want something like this:

```
height: calc(width + 5px);
```

This is just a small example but I'm ultimately looking for a way to use the set width as a part of the calculation, not a simpler way to solve the example. Any searches I do just gives examples on how to use `calc()` to set the width. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe look into JavaScript or some kind of CSS preprocessor. Or just use the same width value in your CSS...

Answer (score 5):

Use a [container query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries). The `cqw` unit represents 1% of the item's width. You can use that unit in your `calc()` function.

I made the item resizable in the following demo, to make the functionality easier to observe.

```css
.container {
  container-type: inline-size;
  background: #ddd;
  
  /* Make resizable, for demo purposes */
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item {
  background: orange;
}

@container (min-width: 0) {
  .item {
    /* 50% of container width + 30px */
    height: calc(50cqw + 30px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">Resize me!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

The closest you might be able to come with pure CSS is combining CSS variables with `calc`

```css
:root {
 --width: 100px;
}
div {
 border: 1px solid red;
 height: calc(var(--width) + 5px);
 width: var(--width);
}
```

```html
<div>
test
</div>
```

This will let you define a CSS variable `--width` and use it to calculate a new height for the div.